# Put div and input in same line inside link

Tags: html, css

I have this link in list with some inputs inside:

```
<ul class="code__list">
    <li class="code__item"> <a class="code__link private" href="#">Test1<b><input type="text" class="intercomInput forCode" name="clientCode" value="1234"></b><div>Test2</div></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

How to place it in one row?
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soycqxwe/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `div` with a `span`, or set the CSS `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block` as below.

```
<ul class="code__list">
    <li class="code__item">
        <a class="code__link private" href="#">Test1
            <b>
                <input type="text" class="intercomInput forCode" name="clientCode" value="1234">
            </b>
            <div style="display: inline-block">Test2</div>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fine. used inline-block. I'll accept you answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: @SergeyScopin why 11 minutes? :P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `div` you can use `span`, because `div` is `block` element and span is `inline`, this is why your content is not showing in one line.

Try this:

```
<ul class="code__list">
    <li class="code__item"> <a class="code__link private" href="#">Test1<b><input type="text" class="intercomInput forCode" name="clientCode" value="1234"></b><span>Test2</span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/soycqxwe/3/)

Comment: In your demo they are not in one line.